# How to delete all files except specific one in Bourne shell?

Tags: linux, sh, node-red

I have a Node-RED flow updating a file with measurements every second, and a new file is created for each day. All the files except the one currently being updated will need to be deleted every few days, which I'm hoping to automate with the Node-Red exec node.

I know the bash command `rm !(filetokeep)` works for this, but Node-RED runs any inputs to the exec node in a Bourne shell, and so this command won't work in the sh shell.

What would the corresponding command for `rm !(filetokeep)` be in a sh shell?

Comment: [Check out this question and answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153862/remove-all-files-directories-except-for-one-file) over on unix.stackexchange.com. The top answer has a few methods for achieving this.

Comment: Node-RED is the only software I've come across that has executable commands running in the Bourne shell by default, and there may be a way to force the exec node to run in a bash shell instead, which would definitely be specific to Node-RED. Also, I don't know how you would use `find` to keep the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node-RED doesn't use any shell when executing commands, it just passes the command to `exec`, so there will be no shell level file globbing passed to the rm command.

The find command will just what you want without having to make any assumptions about the environment the command executes in:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;
```

This will delete all files last modified over 1 day ago from the current working directory (`.`)